# Why Am I Getting A Copy Bundle Resources Warning Even Though The Build Phase Does Not Include The Resource?

Tags: xcode

Please have a look at the first screen shot below. The Issues Navigator contains a Dependency Analysis Warning reporting that the project's info.plist has been added to a target's Copy Bundle Resources build phase. However, examining the target in the Editor reveals that info.plist **is not included** by the build phase.

The second screen shot shows the relevant info.plist. In the File Inspector note that the Target Membership check box is unchecked.

Can anyone help me to resolve this warning?

[image: Copy Bundle Resources Warning]

[image]